# Universal Windows App Visual Studio 2015 Community no designer, no controls in toolbox, no properties

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 to create Universal Windows App.
I am facing following problems-
1. No designer view.
2. No controls in toolbox.
3. Property window don't show any properties of control.
4. No phone emulators are shown after installing EmulatorSetup.exe

[image]

**Visual Studio Installed Components are as follows**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA136

Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA136

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA136

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   4.2.60128.3

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0

Common Azure Tools   1.5

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2   Build 104.0.20151218.120627

JSLint.NET for Visual Studio   2.2.0

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4

NuGet Package Manager   3.3.0

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0

TypeScript   1.7.6.0

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.24720.00

Web Essentials 2015.1   1.0.209

Comment: You could try to install windows 10 sdk https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: I already have it.  win 10 sdk ver 10.0.26624 (size 1.76Gb) and ver 10.1.10586.15 (size 2.15Gb)

Comment: The only think that comes in my mind is repair VS. And that may not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem and the only way I have got the designer to work is (and this should work if build 10240 is acceptable for your development):

1. Open your project
2. Go under "Project" to "Properties"
3. Select "Application" on the left and change BOTH the target version and the min version to "Windows 10 (10.0; Build **10240**)

Once you do that the XAML designer will start working again.  I've had to do this on 4 different workstations and it's worked everytime.

As to why build 10568 doesn't work?  Got me, agile development, will be fixed in a patch? :p

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not change BOTH versions to Build 10240 as the Application listbox only showed 10586 in Properties/Application. I thought I could arrange that by editing the .csproj file, which is XML after all, but any change there makes all files in the Solution Explorer immediately unavailable. Then I noticed (running Winver.exe) that my W10 still shows build 10240 despite regularly (but not automatically) running Windows updates. Despite multiple solutions tried, this didn't change. I finally used the MediaCreation Tool to download a new Windows 10 on a USB stick and reinstalled Windows 10, preserving apps and data. And now I am really on 10586 ...and the Design mode shows again when I open my project.

I hope this helps a few!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the SSIS toolbox, click SSIS tab, then SSIS Toolbox.