# UWP can't set target to Windows 10240

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have some trouble getting started with the Universal Windows Platform.
Herefor I've installed the Visual Studio 2015 Community version, and I can succesfully create an App and run it on my Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT Core. 
But my problem is that I cannot get the designer visible in the XAML files. Now have I found an answer to this in the following post:

[Universal Windows App Visual Studio 2015 Community no designer, no controls in toolbox, no properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769717/universal-windows-app-visual-studio-2015-community-no-designer-no-controls-in-t/35822024#35822024)

Here I read that I have to set my target version to Windows 10240. This could be correct, because my current Windows 10 version is 10240, but for some reason I cannot set it to 10240. I can set the minimum version to 10240, but on the target version is only 10586 visible. Does anyone know what the reason of this is?

Please find the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

I've also tried to get my Windows 10 to update to 10586 (November Update), but this update fails, I guess maybe because my Users directory is on the D: Drive.
[Click here for my Windows Version Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWBae.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this and all related problems, your best bet is to go to the [dev center](http://www.dev.windows.com) and check there.

In this case, it looks like you are missing the SDK that targets the build 10240 of Windows 10, which can be found on this [link](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/sdk-archive).

[image]

Comment: You can also scroll through the Visual Studio Installer list of individual components and grab the SDK you want, which I wouldn't have thought to check without this answer! Thanks!